# InstaPy: "Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit linux"

Tags: python, linux, instapy

Anyone knows how to solve of fix this issue?
Stack trace from console, that reports an error after execution:

```sh
    InstaPy Version: 0.6.9
    ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
    Workspace in use: "/home/zanettra/InstaPy"
    Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit linux
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "unfollow.py", line 24, in <module>
    headless_browser=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 
    322, in __init__
    self.logger,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 114, in set_selenium_local_session
        driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 36, in get_geckodriver
        sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()[1]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 177, in download_and_install
        show_progress_bar=show_progress_bar)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 129, in download
        download_url = self.get_download_url(version, os_name=os_name, bitness=bitness)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 324, in get_download_url
        raise RuntimeError(info_message)
    RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit linux
```

Answer (score 20):

This problem is not related to InstaPy but the webdriverdownloader.py from webdriverdownloader. For Ubuntu you can fix the problem with `sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver`; Other OS will have similar solution to install the geckodirver.

---

For macOS users,
the problem is due to the new arch ARM in macOS `geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz` and `geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos-aarch64.tar.gz`

Available versions Nov 2021:

```py
['geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux32.tar.gz', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux32.tar.gz.asc', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz.asc', 'geckodriver-v0.30
.0-macos-aarch64.tar.gz', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-win32.zip', 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64.zip']
```

You can patch the file for `GeckoDriverDownloader` -> `site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py`
with the following:

```sh
   1   │ diff --git a/Users/user/GitHub/InstaPy/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py b/Users/user/GitHub/InstaPy/venv39/lib/python3.9/
       │ site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader_patch.py
   2   │ index bc01c2d..057862a 100644
   3   │ --- a/Users/user/GitHub/InstaPy/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py
   4   │ +++ b/Users/user/GitHub/InstaPy/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader_patch.py
   5   │ @@ -382,6 +382,13 @@ class GeckoDriverDownloader(WebDriverDownloaderBase):
   6   │              )
   7   │              logger.error(info_message)
   8   │              raise RuntimeError(info_message)
   9   │ +        # macos is only available for 64bit, 32bit is deprectated
  10   │ +        # geckodriver is available for x64 and aarch64, this is why the "RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit macos"
  11   │ +        # geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz
  12   │ +        # geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos-aarch64.tar.gz
  13   │ +        if os_name == "macos":
  14   │ +            bitness = ".tar.gz"  # no bitness for macos since it is 64bit only. Use the extension for tar.gz
  15   │ +
  16   │          if len(filename) > 1:
  17   │              filename = [name for name in filenames if os_name + bitness in name]
  18   │              if len(filename) != 1:
```

Comment: In macos it looks: `brew install geckodriver`

Answer (score 2):

Adding what worked for me on Macos.

Simplest thing to do on is download the drivers from [official latest github link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.29.1) and extract the zip folder.

Create a virtualenv and in the bin folder for the virtualenv add the geckodriver executable.

You can also manually add the path of the geckodriver using sys.path as below:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/myfolder/Downloads/geckodriver')
```

But this wasn't working for me for some reason. Virtualenv solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Works with

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is posted here: https://github.com/leonidessaguisagjr/webdriverdownloader/pull/12

You have to change a line in webdriverdownloader.py
from

```
filename = [name for name in filenames if os_name + bitness in name]
```

to

```
filename = [name for name in filenames if os_name + bitness in name and name[-3:] != 'asc' ]
```

The path that the file was stored in my system was `home/kali/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webdriverdownloader`

I used `pip3 install webdriverdriverdownloader` to find where it's stored

Answer (score 0):

What works for me on macos :

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader.py :

Line 314 change
filename = [name for name in filenames if os_name in name]
to :
filename = [name for name in filenames if 'macos' in name]

Answer (score 0):

in Kali linux:

download the tar file:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.32.0/geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

extract it to:

```
tar xvzf ~/Downloads/geckodriver*.tar.gz -C /tmp/
sudo chown -R root:root /tmp/geckodriver*
```

if you get an error, you need to install

```
 sudo apt install eyewitness
```