# Python Code Error on Mac - What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm no coder, this is my first attempt to coding something.

I followed some instruction on YouTube to create an automation using Python and InstaPy.

The code of the .py file is the following

```
from instapy import InstaPy

from instapy import smart_run

my_username = 'myuser'

my_password = 'mypassword'

session = InstaPy(username=my_username,

password=my_password,

headless_browser=True)

with smart_run(session):

`session.set_relationship_bounds(enable=True,`

delimit_by_numbers=True,

max_followers=600,

min_followers=30,

max_following=600)

`session.like_by_tags(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'], amount=300)`
```

The headless_browser=True because I want to run multiple automatons for different accounts that I have.

At least, based on the tutorials, that's what I think is the correct way.

Using the Terminal, accessing the folder on the desktop where the file is located I run the command python3 test.py

I'm getting a huge error.

I already looked at some post on GtHub that refer to errors on mac

https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/5672

and I've already followed the instruction there, but I still get this error:

```
InstaPy Version: 0.6.13

._. ._. ._. ._. ._. ._. ._. ._.

Workspace in use: "/Users/av/InstaPy"

Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit macos

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/av/Desktop/InstaAuto/test.py", line 7, in <module>

session = InstaPy(username=my_username,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 325, in __init__

self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 122, in set_selenium_local_session

driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 38, in get_geckodriver

sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()[1]

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 174, in download_and_install

filename_with_path = self.download(version,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 129, in download

download_url = self.get_download_url(version, os_name=os_name, bitness=bitness)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 324, in get_download_url

raise RuntimeError(info_message)

RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit macos

AVs-MacBook-Pro:InstaAuto av$
```

​

Can someone help me understand what should I do?

Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: Could you please format the code properly? It's lacking any indentation and that every second line is a blank line makes it hard to read.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235553/instapy-error-unable-to-determine-correct-filename-for-64bit-linux

Comment: Try installing geckodriver: `brew install geckodriver`

Comment: "I'm no coder, this is my first attempt to coding something." Then you should follow a tutorial *for the language itself* and learn the fundamentals, before trying to use a library for some special-purpose thing and typing in a bunch of code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its a current issue on github right now. There are two versions of the gecko driver with the package.

Update line 320 in webdriverdownloader.py to:

```
filename = [name for name in filenames if os_name in name and name[-12:] == 'macos.tar.gz' ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Where I find the webdriverdownloader.py ? I've searched, but it doesn't appear.

Comment: `/Users/mac/Desktop/instapy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriverdownloder/webdriverdownloader.py` is what is mentioned in what i found

Comment: Thank you. As I'm not finding anything, I tried to reinstall, and I got this message: ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.

Comment: I followed the link, but it's a page with a code. What should I do?

Comment: Are you set on using Python 2.7?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know how to answer your question. I've installed, following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-w5ya9abAA

Comment: @AV what does `python --version` say in a command prompt/ terminal?

Comment: The folder in the Application folder says that is a Python 3.9

Comment: @AV but what version of python do you have installed?

Comment: The last one. So 3.9. I guess